# Typescript: Pick only one of union

Tags: typescript

I have this `Query` type with `getBankAccounts` property:

```js
export type Query = {
  getBankAccounts: GetBankAccountsResponseOrUserInputRequest,
};
```

But it returns either a `GetAccountsResponse` or a `UserInputRequest`:

`export type GetBankAccountsResponseOrUserInputRequest = GetAccountsResponse | UserInputRequest;`

I'm looking to `Pick<Query, "getBankAccounts">` only the response type of: `GetAccountsResponse`.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
type BankAccountQuery = Pick<Query, Exclude<keyof Query, 'getBankAccounts'>> & { getBankAccounts: GetAccountsResponse }
```

Or you can use an `Overwrite` helper:

```
type Overwrite<T, U extends { [K in keyof T]?: any }> = U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>;
type BankAccountQuery = Overwrite<Query, {getBankAccounts: GetAccountsResponse }>;
```

Note that this will pick any additional field of `Query` type (if there's any). If you only want to pick exactly one field maybe you can simply declare another type?

```
type BankAccountQuery = {
  getBankAccounts: GetAccountsResponse;
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-D9GgRSAA)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me: `Pick<Query, "getBankAccounts"> & { getBankAccounts: GetAccountsResponse }` without having to `Exclude`